# "'NoneType' object is not iterable" when adding new user on django custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

First of all, I am new to Django. Please tell me if my question is not clear and straightforward.

I was trying to make custom user model for my app, everything seems fine until I found error when trying to add new user in the admin page. The error page was shown after I clicked Add User button on the top right of the page.

*Note:

1. I am using Django 1.10.8
2. I created it in the app named 'accounts'
3. I am trying to get rid of username field (Django's default) and changed it to phone_number as the unique field.
4. I can create superuser (with python manage.py createsuperuser), I can edit it also.

This is the error:

```
    Environment:

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://localhost:8002/admin/accounts/user/add/

    Django Version: 1.10.8
    Python Version: 2.7.10
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



    Traceback:

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
      42.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
      544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
      57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
      211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
      67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
      76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
      63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
      67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
      63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
      185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in add_view
      128.                                                extra_context)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
      1509.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
      67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
      63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
      185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
      1438.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in get_form
      82.         return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_form
      608.             fields = flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj))

    File "/Users/user/Documents/adxasia/jani_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in flatten_fieldsets
      112.     for name, opts in fieldsets:

    Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/accounts/user/add/
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

this is my models.py codes:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, phone_number, password=None):
        """
        For creating users
        """
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('User must have phone number!')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User must have password!')

        user = self.model(
            phone_number = phone_number,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, phone_number, password, first_name, last_name):
        """
        For creating user staff
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            phone_number,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, first_name, last_name, password):
        """
        For creating super user
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            phone_number,
            password=password,
        )
        user.admin = True
        user.staff = True
        user.active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their phone number
        return self.phone_number

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their phone number
        return self.phone_number

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user member of admin?"
        return self.admin
```

and this is my admin.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


User = get_user_model()


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('phone_number', 'password')}),
        ('Bio', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'birth_date')})
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('phone_number', 'password1', 'password2')
        })
    )

    search_fields = ('phone_number', 'full_name')
    list_display = ('phone_number', 'full_name', 'admin', 'staff', 'active')
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'active')
    ordering = ('phone_number',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to add comma after the first tuple, in `add_fieldsets`. Try to copy following piece of code.

```
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('phone_number', 'password1', 'password2')
    }),
)
```

Checked it in console:

```
>>> from django.contrib.admin.utils import flatten_fieldsets
>>> add_fieldsets = ((None, {'classes': ('wide',), 'fields': ('phone_number', 'password1', 'password2')}))
>>> flatten_fieldsets(add_fieldsets)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/yauheni/Dev/clean_django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 112, in flatten_fieldsets
    for name, opts in fieldsets:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>> add_fieldsets = ((None, {'classes': ('wide',), 'fields': ('phone_number', 'password1', 'password2')}),)
>>> flatten_fieldsets(add_fieldsets)
['phone_number', 'password1', 'password2']
>>>
```

**UPD**

This is more pythonic problem, not django's. So you won't find answer in django documentation. Here's the [function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L93) where the error was. To bring you an idea, I'll leave this example:

```
>>> x = ((1, 2))
>>> x[0]
1
>>> x = ((1, 2),)
>>> x[0]
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, Thank you! Can you tell me a clue why it happened? I'll check the documentation later.

Comment: @TijaniRF updated answer with short description of original problem

Comment: My bad, that was a rookie mistake. Thanks for the update!

Comment: This actually a well-known python gotcha: a literal tuple is defined by the trailing coma not the parens - except for the empty tuple which is defined by a pair of parens, and except that you still need the parens in some places to disambiguate the expression (ie if you want to use a literal tuple in an expression where the coma has another meaning - function call, literal list of tuples etc).